# ios - unable to erase the UIImage like Rubber

Tags: objective-c, opengl-es, quartz-graphics, core-image

in my app i have two views one above the other. I the below view i have a captured image and in the above view i have placed an image. If the user needs to make some changes in the above image i am giving them an option of erasing the image.

Everything is working fine the problem is if i am trying to erase the image it seems to be a broken one. The image is not getting deleted in a gentle way. when i erase it looks like the below one.
[image: Here I get The erased Image]

I want it to be as follow
[image]

how to do this, pls help me

Following is my code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(frontImage.frame.size);
        [frontImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, frontImage.frame.size.width, frontImage.frame.size.height)];
        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound); 
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 10);
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1, 0, 0, 10);
        CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextClearRect (UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y, 50, 50));
        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        frontImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: use this line of joining ends: CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);

Comment: Thanks for yor reply, Here i used these lines of code still now i didnt get.In the above i have added the code what i have implemented

Comment: thanks,but i using ccsprite in bounding box to erase image in game in cocos2d so plz...help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a square brush, and you're only erasing that square at a single point on the line the user drew. Also, your stroke color is completely wrong for what you're trying to do.

It looks like you're trying to set the stroke to a clear color and draw a line between the previous and current points. If you want to do that, you should do this:

```
CGContextRef currCtx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor (currCtx, 0, 0, 0, 0);
CGContextMoveToPoint (currCtx, startPt.x, startPt.y);
CGContextLineToPoint (currCtx, endPt.x, endPt.y);
```

In this case startPt.x/y is the location of the previous touch, and endPt.x/y is the current touch.

Note that to get lines as nice as in the picture you posted, you'll need to actually use an antialiased texture and draw it at every point along the line, varying its size. But the above should get you something workable that looks pretty good.

Comment: Thank, Still i a have a same problem

Comment: I don't understand your last comment, but did you remove the call to `CGContextClearRect()`? That's what's causing your blockiness. Also, set the line cap as mentioned by Shehzad Bilal above.

Comment: thanks,but i using ccsprite in bounding box to erase image in game in cocos2d so plz...help

Answer (score 0):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView1.frame.size);
[imageView1.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0,imageView1.frame.size.width, imageView1.frame.size.height)];
CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext( ),kCGBlendModeClear);
CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext( ), 25.0);

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]);
CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), point.x, point.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), point.x, point.y);
CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()) ;

imageView1.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```